# My Jsonobject is going back to null?

Tags: android, json, oop

I am struggling with an issue that I can't seem to make sense of.

I have downloaded my json feed which I am storing as text.  I am creating a new instance of my JsonDataReader class which parses my jsonfeed into class properties.

When I debug- I can see that the class properties are correctly being created however when my main activity resumes the object doesn't seem to have any properties ie it( has gone back to null)

Is there an issue with the way I am calling it?

```
DKEntryJsonDataReader dkjsdr = null;

                try {
                    dkjsdr = new DKEntryJsonDataReader(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
setContentView(R.layout.dk_entry_parentview);
    //grab the views
                    TextView title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dk_titlelisting);
                    TextView body=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dk_bodylisting);  
                    title.setText(dkjsdr.titletext);  //returns as null!
                    body.setText(dkjsdr.pText);   //returns as null!
```

Edit:

Ok - looks like I have just worked it out.  The reason that the object was coming up as null was that the Json didn't have all the required fields in so was erroring out before completing the constructing class.  So might be worth putting a validity checker in prior to parsing.

Discovered this by using the wonders of debugging the error code. (e)
am adding Log.e!

Comment: Please post your **edit** as an answer to your question, and then accept it whenever time allows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - looks like I have just worked it out. The reason that the object was coming up as null was that the Json didn't have all the required fields in so was erroring out before completing the constructing class. So might be worth putting a validity checker in prior to parsing.

Discovered this by using the wonders of debugging the error code. (e) am adding Log.e!